# Interpreter - value of variable define the type

Tags: interpreter

I am writing a simple interpreter for quazi JavaScript language. In JavaScript the type of variable is defined by the value of it. I tried to google some simple solutions for source code or some explanations how to do this kind of things. I don't know really where to ask for help and that's Why I am asking you guys for some articles or git's projects. Thanks!!!

Comment: What language are you writing your interpreter in?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, variables actually don't *have* type. *Values* have type, and variables have values. You can inspect the type of the *current value* of a variable, but you can always assign any other value to the variable. A term sometimes used for this type of variable is a "variant". This is one option you could choose for your language.

If you want to have typed variables, then you will need static analysis of expressions. Once you parse a line of code such as:

```
var x = a.function() + b;
```

...before you can start executing it, you'll need to look at `a.function` and `b` to determine the data types they'll return, then derive the type that `operator +` returns given those two types as input -- then that can be assigned as the variable type for `x`.

This is substantially more work to do, and introduces a whole new category of errors that prevent the code from being executed in the first-place ("compile-time" errors).

You're probably looking for the first approach, and for that approach, you need a data structure that combines a value with a description of the value's type, and that unit together is what you assign to variables, perform computations on, return from functions, etc. If you're lucky, the language you're writing your interpreter in will already come with such a concept -- for instance, if you're writing your interpreter in JavaScript, then you can just use values directly, as they already encapsulate the concept. If you're writing your interpreter in Java or C#, then the `Object` type can refer to any value, and the language's type system (and, if necessary, reflection) can be used to inspect the type.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The kind of variables that store various types is called a "variant". Basically, what you do is that each variable has to be large enough to hold all the types your language has, plus a marker what type it currently is. For example, in C you would use a Union for this:

```
struct Variant
{
    enum VariantTypeEnum
    {
        VARIANT_TYPE_INT,
        VARIANT_TYPE_STRING,
        VARIANT_TYPE_BOOL
    } type; 
    union VariantUnion
    {
        int intValue;
        char* stringValue;
        bool boolValue;
    } value;
};
```

When you have a variable of this type, you can now assign both types to it and mark which one it is, then run different code depending on what type it is:

```
Variant  x;
x.type = VARIANT_TYPE_INT;
x.value.intValue = 42;
```

Usually you'd write a utility function that converts to the desired types so your interpreter doesn't have to worry what type it actually is unless it's a type which it can't convert to:

```
char* CopyStringFromVariant( Variant* inVariant )
{
    if( inVariant->type == VARIANT_TYPE_STRING )
    {
        int strSize = strlen(inVariant.value.stringValue) +1;
        char* strCopy = malloc(strSize);
        memmove(strCopy,inVariant.value.stringValue, strSize);
        return strCopy;
    }
    else if( inVariant->type == VARIANT_TYPE_BOOL )
    {
        const char* boolStr = inVariant.value.boolValue ? "true" : "false";
        int strSize = strlen(boolStr) +1;
        char* strCopy = malloc(strSize);
        memmove(strCopy, boolStr, strSize);
        return strCopy;
    }
    else if( inVariant->type == VARIANT_TYPE_INT )
    {
        char strBuf[11] = {};
        snprintf( strBuf, sizeof(strBuf) -1, "%d", inVariant.value.intValue );
        int strSize = strlen(strBuf) +1;
        char* strCopy = malloc(strSize);
        memmove(strCopy, strBuf, strSize);
        return strCopy;
    }
    else
        return NULL; // Indicate error.
}
```

If you are not writing a pure line-wise interpreter (i.e. this is not an artificially restricted homework assignment), but are permitted to create a bit of a hybrid, you could parse the code into a tree structure first, and then walk the tree nodes and figure out their types. Use a bit field or a set to keep track of which types values stored in a variable have, based on what operations are applied. E.g. if there is a division result stored in a variable, the end result *must* be a number from then on.

Once you've analyzed the whole script like that, you can then generate the code. This works for most valid programs, but some JavaScript variables may "change types" during a program's run. Those you'd then either still have to implement as variants, or as strings (which can store a fairly inefficient representation of all other types), and then convert using `GetIntFromString()` functions in the style of the `CopyStringFromVariant()` example I gave.

Disclaimer: All code written right here in the submit form, it may have typos and not compile.

**Note:** Another approach is to [do it like Smalltalk](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/musings/SmalltalkOverview.html), where a variable is usually a pointer to an object, but some simple types are encoded using values that would be invalid pointers (e.g. odd addresses, which most allocators will not give you, so are impossible if your address points to the start of an object).